# Can't Persist New User to Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've been reading countless tutorials and I'm not able to get any data to appear in the firebase database at all. I'm trying to get this structure

```
"my-app-name": {
    "users": {
        "uid-of-user": {
            "email": "them@them.com",
            "todoitems": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First of all I'm not sure how to acquire that structure. Under `"my-app-name"` in the visual editor, I've put `"users" = ""`. I'm not sure if that's the way to star establishing `users` as an empty object. Or maybe I shouldn't be dealing with the visual editor at all? Here's my `createNewUser` controller that should be persisting new users to the database:

```
function LoginController($scope, Auth, $state, $location, $firebaseObject, $firebase) {
    $scope.createNewUser = createNewUser;
    $scope.signupComplete = "";

    function createNewUser() {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://sizzling-torch-655.firebaseio.com/");

        //CREATE USER
        Auth.$createUser({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        }).then(function(userData) {

            //THIS SHOULD BE PERSISTING IT TO THE DATABASE
            var user = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(userData.uid));
            user.$loaded().then(function() {
                var newUser = {
                    emailAddress: $scope.email,
                };
                user.$ref.$set(newUser);
            })
            // $location.path("/home");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.responseMessage = error;
        });
    };
};
```

It should be noted I haven't created the users object yet in the firebase database. Any help is extremely appreciated. Thank you very much.

**Clarification**

`Auth.$creatUser` is:

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);
```

I've successfully created users and see them appear in the Login/Users tab of the Firebase dashboard. I'm not able to store them into the database though.

And `userData.uid` is the `userData` object that was returned from the `then` part of the `$createUser` function.

**EDIT 2**
These are my security and rules. Could this be affecting me writing user data to the database?
This is going to be a todo app. Users should be able to only have access to their own data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    // public read access
    ".read": true,

    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so what's Auth.$createUser ? is userData.uid valid ? Have you tried their example: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-createusercredentials ?

Comment: I've made some edits to the question. To clarify, I'm able to create users, just not store them in the database.

Comment: hm something similar works on my end. So in the editor you don't need to enter anything. Everything gets created by the app. $ref is not a property it's a function but you shouldn't need it. Can you create a plunkr? and let the database accessible by anyone?

Comment: you should be able to just say: user.email = 'whatever' and then user.$save()

Comment: How do I make the database accessible to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically store user information in the database. If you want to store such information in the database, you will have to write the necessary code for that yourself.

From your snippet:

```
//THIS SHOULD BE PERSISTING IT TO THE DATABASE
var user = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(userData.uid));
```

This code does **not** store any information in the database either. Instead it tries to **read** the user's data from the database. But since you didn't write it there in the first place, the read will accomplish nothing and the `then()` will never execute.

The solution is to write the necessary user data into the database, when the user authenticates.

```
var user = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(userData.uid));
var newUser = {
    emailAddress: $scope.email,
};
user.$ref.$set(newUser);
```

Comment: thank you but I have one question. In my database, I don't have `users` created yet. Will it create it automatically or should I create it using `users=""`. I ask because I know you need to assign it a value, I'm not sure how to tell the graphical interface it's going to be an empty object.

Comment: When you create a value at a path, Firebase will create all intermediate nodes that are necessary automatically. When no value exists on a certain path anymore, all intermediate nodes are automatically removed. So you don't have to worry about those in either direction.

Comment: please check out my second edit in the question. I just realized my Security and Rules I created might be affecting this process. I copied and pasted it from somewhere so that other users couldn't write data that wasn't theirs.

Comment: The security rules seem fine, but your `$loaded()` will never fire. I updated my answer.